# Populating razor DropDownList from view model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a custom model (let's say CustomModel) for populating my razor DropDownList in the view:

```
namespace MyNamespace.Models
{
    public class SelectListItem
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    public class ComponentTypeModel
    {
        private readonly List<ComponentType> componentTypes;

        [Display(Name = "Component Type")]
        public int SelectedCompTypeId { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CompTypeItems
        {
            get
            {
                var allCompTypes = componentTypes.Select(f => new SelectListItem
                {
                    Value = f.Id.ToString(),
                    Text = f.Name
                });

                return allCompTypes;
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DefaultCompTypeItem
        {
            get
            {
                return Enumerable.Repeat(new SelectListItem
                                               {
                                                   Value = "-1",
                                                   Text = "Select a component type"
                                               }, 
                                         count: 1);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Then in my view I do the following using razor:

```
@model MyNamespace.Models.CustomModel

@Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedCompTypeId);
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedCompTypeId, Model.CompTypeItems);
```

but the second argument **Model.CompTypeItems** in line:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedCompTypeId, Model.CompTypeItems);
```

is generating a compilation error saying that it is not valid. Any ideas?

Comment: The syntax for DropdownListFor is correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are complicating yourself.

Just use this model:

```
public class ComponentTypeModel
{
    public int? SelectedComp {get; set;}
    public SelectList DDLCompTypes {get; set;}
}
```

Then in your controller:

```
var model = new ComponentTypeModel();
model.DDLCompTypes = new SelectList(theComponentTypes, "Id","Name");

//If you need to set some value in the DropDownValue (for instance in the Edit view) you do:
model.DDLCompTypes = new SelectList(theComponentTypes, "Id","Name", model.SelectedComp);
```

Then in your View:

```
@Html.DropDownFor(x => x.SelectedComp, Model.DDLCompTypes, "Select a component type" )
```

Comment: I have solved. It is not necessary to create a custom SelectListItem as it is defined in .NET framework in assembly using System.Web.Mvc so including this in my model solved the issue.

Comment: what is theComponentTypes ?

Comment: @Mou theComponentTypes is a collection of Component Types.